# Store data from a dynamically generated form in an array

Tags: php, forms, loops, for-loop

I have created a for loop that generates a form div repeatedly:

```
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $noOfTanks; $i++) {
  echo '<div class="';
  echo $col;
  echo  '"><img id="tank" src="img/tank.svg" alt="Tank"></br>
        <label for="tankName';
  echo  $i;
  echo '">Tank Name ';
  echo  $i;
  echo  '</label>
        <input type="text" id="tankName';
  echo  $i;
  echo '" name="tankName';
  echo  $i;
  echo '"></br>
        <label class="rightT" for="tankVolume';
  echo  $i;
  echo  '">Tank Volume ';
  echo  $i;
  echo  '</label>
          <input class="rightT" type="text" id="tankVolume';
  echo  $i;
  echo  '" name="tankVolume';
  echo  $i;
  echo  '"><p>L</p>
        </div>';}
```

The code generated a number of inputs. I want to gather all this input values into two arrays tankName[], tankVolume[]. I am struggling to understand how to use $_POST to do this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array` of inputs.

Example:

```
<input class="rightT" type="text" id="tankVolume1" name="tankVolume[]"/>
```

Comment: If I want to collect the data into a PHP array is this a correct code:

if ($submit=='Finish Setup')
    {
        if (isset($_POST["tankName"])) {
            foreach ($_POST["tankName"] as $key => $tankName){

          $tankName=trim($tankName);
        }
            }else{
          $tankName='';
                  }
    }

Comment: It will return an array at server side. You will get all values in `$_POST["tankName"]`.